# Sbt Cannot Resolve "latest.integration" Version

Tags: sbt

When I try to resolve the following dependency with Sbt `"com.dixa"        %  "conversation-thrift-protocol" % "latest.integration"`, it fails with:

```
[error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.dixa:conversation-thrift-protocol:latest.integration
[error]   not found: https://repo.dixa.io/content/repositories/snapshots/com/dixa/conversation-thrift-protocol/maven-metadata.xml
```

As a matter of fact, the referred `maven-metadata.xml` file does exist in Nexus repo, which leaves me puzzled. Where should I look for a problem?

The contents of the `maven-metadata.xml` file:

```
<metadata>
<groupId>com.dixa</groupId>
<artifactId>conversation-thrift-protocol</artifactId>
<versioning>
<versions>
<version>7.10.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<version>7.10.1--v2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<version>7.10.1-v2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<version>7.10.1-v6-SNAPSHOT</version>
<version>7.10.1-v7-SNAPSHOT</version>
</versions>
<lastUpdated>20220517141646</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be a problem with indexing of the repository: the published artifacts were not visible straight away, they needed some time before becoming visible for resolvers